# Best partitioning solution for MySQL query on datetime column

Tags: mysql

I have a simple query over a MySQL table with around 500 millions rows but it's not fast despite  of indexing and partitioning.
I created below table:

```
CREATE TABLE `foo` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_added` datetime  DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `height` double DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`date_added`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

then I did partitioning like below:

```
ALTER TABLE foo PARTITION BY RANGE (MONTH(date_added))
(
PARTITION p01 VALUES LESS THAN (02) ,
PARTITION p02 VALUES LESS THAN (03) ,
PARTITION p03 VALUES LESS THAN (04) ,
PARTITION p04 VALUES LESS THAN (05) ,
PARTITION p05 VALUES LESS THAN (06) ,
PARTITION p06 VALUES LESS THAN (07) ,
PARTITION p07 VALUES LESS THAN (08) ,
PARTITION p08 VALUES LESS THAN (09) ,
PARTITION p09 VALUES LESS THAN (10) ,
PARTITION p10 VALUES LESS THAN (11) ,
PARTITION p11 VALUES LESS THAN (12) ,
PARTITION p12 VALUES LESS THAN (13) ,
PARTITION pmaxval VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE 
);
```

below is my query that getting slow over time.

```
SELECT `date_added`, 
       `height` FROM foo 
WHERE name= 'Jack' 
AND date_added >= '2023-06-01' 
ORDER BY date_added ASC;
```

It seems that partitioning is useless as I'm not searching based on month(date_added).
what is the best partitioning in this case?

Comment: create a index on date_added. a composite index can only be used from left to right. in your case you can use id or id plus date_added but never date_added only

Comment: And you partitioning is useless as you are not searching based on month(date_added) and the month() function cannot return more than 12.

Comment: I created an index on name column. is it useless?

Comment: what kind of partitioning should I use?

Comment: You should read [Partition Pruning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning-pruning.html). Your current partitioning is going to make your example query slower, if anything. Partitioning by `YEAR(date_added)` or `TO_DAYS(date_added)` _may_ be beneficial for your example query, but may be bad for other queries. Without understanding the distribution of your data and all the different ways that your data is accessed, it is impossible to suggest _"the best"_ partitioning scheme. For your example query you would be better off adding an index on `(date_added)` or `(name, date_added)`.

Comment: Assuming there are lots of `height`s per `name`, you should move `name` to a `people` (or `names`, whatever) table and reference it with FK from the `foo` (`measurements`, maybe?) table, with `(person_id, date_added)` becoming the PK. Also, do not set `DEFAULT NULL` unless you _really need_ to allow `NULL` values in those columns.